# Laravel Application Response Time Slow on Kubernetes (EKS) vs. Baremetal

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-5, kubernetes

I am in the process of migrating our Laravel application to EKS Kubernetes which is currently running on Docker however the response time is significantly slower.

**The current response time is roughly (Docker): 350-450 ms

The new response time is roughly (Kubernetes): 750-1100 ms**

**Notable Environment Differences:**

- Source code is mounted as a volume in the Docker environment vs.  Kubernetes environment has the source code baked into the image (with PVC's for the storage folder)
- Docker environment is running on a bare metal server vs. Kubernetes is on AWS's EKS

**APM Findings:**

I am running DataDog which shows that a lot of time is being spent on Laravel, rather than DB or Redis which doesn't give me much to work with.

[image]

At this point, I am thinking it is infrastructure related rather than an issue with Laravel as the Docker environment already preforms (decently).

I am running this as an init container (which occurs every deployment or pod restart):

```
php artisan opcache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan view:cache
php artisan opcache:compile --force
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan db:new_seed
php artisan queue:restart
```

I am unsure where to start troubleshooting. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm having a similar issue with my app. But it only help on an auth/login route- it takes 10 seconds! I logged messages and times within that single controller method and it took less than 1 second to hit postgresql on a separate server and redis. I thought it was ingress or something else, but i did a curl on the container and it was just as long.

Comment: I’m not sure if you have the same issue as me but for me was that the region I selected us-east1 was too far from Toronto. Once I changed to ca-central1 the response times increased significantly.

Comment: ahh ok. I'm on GCP - it turned out to be the network storage i have attached to my nodes. I forgot to switch cache and session to redis from disk. Once i did that, i was back in business.